# RTSP Video is not playing in Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android

Can RTSP video be played in Android MediaPlayer? If so how to do it? I am getting the error of server died error(100,0) This is my coding part
    package com.example.samplemedia;

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback,
        OnPreparedListener,OnBufferingUpdateListener,OnErrorListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceView playerSurfaceView;
    String videoSrc = "rtsp://r3---sn-a5m7zu7s.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnZtkPljfg7OhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playerSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.playersurface);

        surfaceHolder = playerSurfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        mp = this.mediaPlayer;
        percent = 90;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }




}
```

and this is my Logcat result where i am getting the result
07-09 12:17:05.484: E/MediaPlayer(3990): error (1, -2147483648)
07-09 12:17:05.484: W/System.err(3990): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at com.example.samplemedia.MainActivity.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:52)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:1126)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:186)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1642)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2467)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-09 12:17:05.494: W/System.err(3990):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**07-09 12:17:05.574: I/MediaPlayer(3990): Info (701,0)
07-09 12:17:07.784: W/AudioSystem(3990): AudioFlinger server died!
07-09 12:17:07.784: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(3990): media server died
07-09 12:17:07.784: E/MediaPlayer(3990): error (100, 0)
07-09 12:17:07.784: E/MediaPlayer(3990): error (100, 0)
07-09 12:17:07.784: E/MediaPlayer(3990): Error (100,0)
07-09 12:17:07.784: E/MediaPlayer(3990): Error (100,0)**

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can considering that RTSP is one of the supported formats by android MediaPlayer.
Here is a short example of how you can play an RTSP from youtube.

```
      public void startPlayer(final String videoSrc, final SurfaceHolder holder) {

      videoSource = "rtsp://v6.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQkDsLHya4-" +
            "Z9hMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYKX4k4uBjbOiUQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";

      if (videoSource != null) {

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        try {

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            final Surface surface = holder.getSurface();

            if (surface == null) {
                return;
            }

            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
      Log.i(tag, "onPrepared...mediaPlayer.start()");
      try {
          mediaPlayer.start();
      } catch (final Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Hope it helps;)